# how to improve text classifier's performance? (how to implement Bernoulli's NaiveBayes with e1071 package's default naive bayes?)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

beginner here trying to learn text analytics...

**short version:**

The package e1071 contains the basic naive bayes. 
how can i tweek it so that i can implement bernoulli's naivebayes with this?

And from what i understand, bernoulli's NB is when the labeling is binary. 
so does that mean if i feed in a binary label into the default/regular NB, i'll be getting a bernoulli's NB?

**long version:**

What I am trying to do is to do text analysis/sentiment analysis on tweets. 
I have a set of data with two columns, one is the tweet text, one is the sentiment label, 1 or 0 (indicating positive or negative).

I created a document term matrix using:

```
tdm.train = TermDocumentMatrix(
  corpus.train,
  control = list(
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stopwords = stopwords(kind = "en"),
    removeNumbers = TRUE, 
    tolower = TRUE,
    weighting = weightTfIdf)
)
```

And then i applied LSA:

```
lsa.train = lsa(tdm.train, dimcalc_share())
```

then i projected the original data matrix into the LSA space:

```
projected.train = fold_in(as.matrix(tdm.train), LSAspace = lsa.train)
```

i converted this projected text matrix into a regular matrix so i can pass into the naive bayes (im using the one from package e1071):

```
projected.train.matrix = matrix(projected.train, 
                                nrow = dim(projected.train)[1],
                                ncol = dim(projected.train)[2])
```

and finally, i use this new matrix to train my naivebayes:

```
NBclassifier = naiveBayes(t(projected.train.matrix), data.train$Sentiment)
```

and then for test set, i did the same preparation steps by turning it into term document matrix and project onto new LSA space. however, the result produced by using naivebayes is not very desirable: only 50% accuracy, 50% precision, 50% recall.

i read this article: 
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-supervised-learning-algorithms-for-sentiment-analysis-in-text
saying that using bernoulli's NB will help improve the performance. 
My question is, how can I tweek my current code to achieve the desired state? (meaning, whether make it into bernoulli's NB, or other ways to improve my classifier accuracy/precision/recall?)

Comment: Check out `RTexttools` package. I think NB is missing from that but you can implement up to 9 techniques (SVM, NNET, GLMNET, ...) and compare the results...

Comment: hi @Sotos. i looked into that package, and seems like i can use cross-validation to apply these 9 techniques. is there any way to implement them directly?